# Data not showing into QTD,YTD into SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to write MDX query for QTD,YTD and MTD in ssas calculation tab but these queries not working ,when i filter data into ssas cube or in excel file its showing #Value! in measures .My MDX queries mentioned below.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].YTDSales as
SUM
(
YTD([Dim Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]),
[Measures].[Sales Amount - Fact Internet Sales]
)
,FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"
,VISIBLE = 1; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].QTDSales as
SUM
(
QTD([Dim Date].[Calendar Quarter].[Calendar Quarter]),
[Measures].[Sales Amount - Fact Internet Sales]

)
,FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"
,VISIBLE = 1; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].MTDSales as
SUM
(
MTD([Dim Date].[English Month Name].[English Month Name]),
[Measures].[Sales Amount - Fact Internet Sales]

)
,FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"
,VISIBLE = 1;
```

Comment: You can get informative error message from the Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

**[Dim Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]** is a level, according to the documentation you have to pass a member. Probably you meant **YTD([Dim Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember)**.

Comment: I am sorry after used your mdx its again showing #Value! in measures ,not showing data.

Comment: That means you didn't set the corresponding type for your [Dim Date] attributes (it doesn't know what is Year level). Also you can set your level using PeriodsToDate([Dim Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year],[Dim Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember) instead, as *TD-like functions are simply shortcuts to your PeriodsToDate passing the first parameter hard-coded .